# How processing all request inside one servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat

I write a webapplication in java with tomcat. I write sevlets, for processing login, registration and other. This sevlets are similari. I want combine them into one, but I don't know how I can do this.

Can you give me advise or link how to fix this problem?

This is my servlets:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/loginForm.jsp");
        view.forward(request,response);
    }
}

@WebServlet("/controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = new User("qwert", "qwerty","qwerty",0);
        req.setAttribute("User", user);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/booksUser.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req,resp);
    }
}

@WebServlet("/registration")
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        view.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: What similarity do you mean?

Comment: You can map multiple URI patterns onto a single servlet class if you wish: `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/login", "/controller", "/registration"})`. But why would you want to combine different units of functionality into the same class? Why not have separate servlets, and separate out common functionality into additional supporting classes?

Comment: *How processing all request inside one servlet?. I write sevlets, for processing login, registration and other* - please, do not ever do this.

Comment: I think that doGet void in two sevlets is identical. I can get all request like this @WebServlet("/"), but how can I do different response logik for these request?

Comment: You *can*, maybe, but think of how it would look in terms of design? would you like to have your bedroom, kitchen and a toilet, all in one square room? separate your concerns. With respect to *how to response according to the logic* - I don't know what the logic you want to have.. write some `if-else` statements.